# ssh host key management between ha hosts

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, high-availability, ssh-keys

We have a setup with 2 Redhat-based servers which are both ha hosts behind a virtual ip.

- 192.168.0.3 dataserver (virtual ip)
- 192.168.0.1 dataserver_ha1 (physical server)
- 192.168.0.2 dataserver_ha2 (physical server)

using drdb and heartbeat it is setup to run one host as a primary host and the other in a standby state. If the primary fails than the standby server become primary and takes over...
Very standard in that regard.

our log processing server (etl_server) sshes to dataserver and runs hourly processes.

We use ssh_keys to connect (though that is not important info for this).

When dataserver_ha1 fails over to ha2, etl_server can no longer connect due to the man-in-the-middle warning about changed host keys.

AFAIK there are a few things I could do:

1) turn strict checking off on the ssh clients (dont want to do that)
2) add entries fro both physical host keys in authorized_keys file on the client
3) mirror all the  /etc/sshd/hosts* files

But I feel like I should be able to tell the hosts to inform the ssh client request that one of two permissible host keys could possibly be used. When I get a little time I will test this out using VirtualBox or something. In the meantime I am looking in the wrong places for info on this...

Comment: What is your problem with turning off the host-key-check? You are just triggering remote scripts. If they are not there - so what?

Answer (score 4):

Use the same private keys on your two dataservers.

From the primary...

`scp /etc/ssh/*key* dataserver_ha2:/etc/ssh/`

Following that, restart the ssh daemon on dataserver_ha2 with `service sshd restart`.

That will take care of your host identity issues in the quickest, cleanest way.